# Error: render function or template not defined in component: anonymous

Tags: node.js, vue.js, vue-ssr

Trying the example from the guide from https://ssr.vuejs.org/guide/#using-a-page-template but there must be something missing in the tutorial.

```
const Vue = require('vue');
const server = require('express')();
const vssr = require('vue-server-renderer');

server.get('*', (req, res) => {
    const renderer = vssr.createRenderer({
        template: require('fs').readFileSync('./templates/index.html', 'utf-8')
    });

    const context = {
        title: 'hello',
        meta: `
            <meta ...>
            <meta ...>
        `
    };

    const app = new Vue({});

    renderer.renderToString(app, context, (err, html) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            process.exit();
        }
        console.log(html);
    });

});

server.listen(6081);
```

When I open my page, I get the error:

> Error: render function or template not defined in component: anonymous
>
> at normalizeRender

Comment: Try providing a `template` property in your Vue instance. `new Vue({ template: \`<div>Hello there!</div>\` })`

Comment: @AnaLizaPandac that's it! I thought the I declared the template by using `template: require('fs').readFileSync('./templates/index.html', 'utf-8')` but the component itself needs another template. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try providing a `template` property or a `render` function in your Vue instance.

```
new Vue({ template: `<div>Hello there!</div>` })
```

The following lines below only means that you want to use your own page template for the renderer where your app's markup will be injected later.

```
const renderer = vssr.createRenderer({
    template: require('fs').readFileSync('./templates/index.html', 'utf-8')
});
```